# How to add new rows to a Pandas dataframe by using previous rows in a time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, append

I have the following dataframe:

```
   date         t       t-7     t-14
   2022-12-07   *4729*  4537    4758
   2022-12-08   5382    5348    5494
   2022-12-09   1969    1902    1965
   2022-12-10   26      20      20
   2022-12-11   13      14      10
   2022-12-12   5055    4866    4733
   2022-12-13   6128    5927    6166
   2022-12-14   3599    *4729*    4515
```

My goal is to add rows by incrementing the date by one day at each row till a given date and to fill the column *t-7* by the value of *t* at shift(7) and *t-14* by the value of *t* at shift(14), as we can see for the date *2022-12-14* the corresponding value of *t-7* is the value of *t* at *2022-12-07*.

Any help is priceless!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the expected output? Can you explain please?

Comment: ...and give a dataframe to work with

Answer (score 0):

Some information about the result you want to obtain is missing.

How should the column 't' be filled in?  How should the t-14 column be filled in when there are not enough rows to go back 14 days?
In the absence of information I have filled in from zero.

Here is how you could do to add 30 lines for example, if I understood the problem well.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

data = {'date': [date(2022, 12, 7), date(2022, 12, 8), date(2022, 12, 9), date(2022, 12, 10), date(2022, 12, 11),
                 date(2022, 12, 12), date(2022, 12, 13), date(2022, 12, 14)],
        't': ['*4729*', 5382, 1969, 26, 13, 5055, 6128, 3599],
        't-7': [4537, 5348, 1902, 20, 14, 4866, 5927, '*4729*'],
        't-14': [4758, 5494, 1965, 20, 10, 4733, 6166, 4515]}

num_rows_to_add = 30

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

last_date = df['date'].iloc[-1]

for i in range(num_rows_to_add):
    df = df.append({'date': last_date + timedelta(days=i + 1),
                    't': 0,
                    't-7': df['t'].iloc[-7],
                    't-14': df['t'].iloc[-14] if len(df) > 13 else 0},
                   ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Sortie

```
         date       t     t-7    t-14
0   2022-12-07  *4729*    4537    4758
1   2022-12-08    5382    5348    5494
2   2022-12-09    1969    1902    1965
3   2022-12-10      26      20      20
4   2022-12-11      13      14      10
5   2022-12-12    5055    4866    4733
6   2022-12-13    6128    5927    6166
7   2022-12-14    3599  *4729*    4515
8   2022-12-15       0    5382       0
9   2022-12-16       0    1969       0
10  2022-12-17       0      26       0
11  2022-12-18       0      13       0
12  2022-12-19       0    5055       0
13  2022-12-20       0    6128       0
14  2022-12-21       0    3599  *4729*
15  2022-12-22       0       0    5382
16  2022-12-23       0       0    1969
17  2022-12-24       0       0      26
18  2022-12-25       0       0      13
19  2022-12-26       0       0    5055
20  2022-12-27       0       0    6128
21  2022-12-28       0       0    3599
22  2022-12-29       0       0       0
23  2022-12-30       0       0       0
24  2022-12-31       0       0       0
25  2023-01-01       0       0       0
26  2023-01-02       0       0       0
27  2023-01-03       0       0       0
28  2023-01-04       0       0       0
29  2023-01-05       0       0       0
30  2023-01-06       0       0       0
31  2023-01-07       0       0       0
32  2023-01-08       0       0       0
33  2023-01-09       0       0       0
34  2023-01-10       0       0       0
35  2023-01-11       0       0       0
36  2023-01-12       0       0       0
37  2023-01-13       0       0       0
```